# Database Query executes slower on production vs. test, on same server, same DB structure

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a web page that is loading using a DB SELECT query that the page is making, to a view table that joins several core tables.

The load time was fast enough (according to tools like Google Page Speed and PingDom), but recently, for a reason I can't figure, it suddenly became slower.

However, if I change the same page to load the query from the DB of the test user, and not the production user (who are both on the same server and IP), it will load fast as it used to. So I can eliminate the possibility that another process on the server is causing the slow down, as otherwise it would effect test user as well.

As far as I can see, I have a similar DB structure (same Primary and Secondary Keys, and the tables are using the same engines, usually INNODB), so I think I can also eliminate the cause a non-optimized DB structure.

Only other difference is that on production I have 500 items, and on test 400 items, but I doubt this is significant, as any way my DB query should only load data from one item at a time.

What else could I check for? Is there a good tool to compare between the structures to be sure it's identical?

I'm running on Centos 7.5 according to WHM panel.

Comment: Usually, production systems have a higher load than tests systems because there are more users. Have you tried reproducing it with a comparable load?

Comment: It's not the issues, since I don't have many users on production, sometime not even 1. also, I tested on hours like very late at night when there are absolute zero users and still getting same results. also, same production server used to work at good speed up until recently, and I can't recall any noticeable change being made.

Comment: Without more information, for example the actual query, DDL of involved tables, indexes, number of records, query plans, etc this will be a guessing game and for too broad. Please edit your question to provide more information.

Comment: What's the best way to obtain all of this data? is there some tool that can run it?

Comment: The first step would be to add the real SQL query that is becoming slow. Second, it would be very useful to get the "execution plan". To do this prepend "explain" to your select, as in `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`. Please add the result you see, to this question.